# Find the velocity of rope falling off table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction

A uniform rope of total length sits on a table

$L = 2m$

A portion of the rope hangs off of the edge of the table

$l = 2/3 m$

The coefficient of static friction between the rope and the table is

$K_s = 0.5$

and the coefficient of kinetic friction is

$K_k = 0.4$

How fast  will the rope be moving when it completely falls off of the top surface of the table?

---

**What I've tried**

I've tried finding the total force so that I get a net force downwards by subtracting the friction force off of gravitational force

Note: I have set the mass of the rope to 2kg so that the length = the weight

$F_g - F_f = F_t = (2/3)(9.8) - (0.4)(4/3)(9.8) = 1.30666N$

- But I quickly realised that the amount of friction and mass is going to decrease as other part of rope accelerates towards the ground.
- Which means the acceleration is not going to be constant but increasing due to the extra mass falling off.

---

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Consider an energy approach: the gravitational potential of the rope just hanging before dropping away, minus the work done by friction, is the kinetic energy. From that, you find speed.

Comment: @BobJacobsen That sounds like it should be an answer

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an energy approach: the gravitational potential of the rope just hanging before dropping away, minus the work done by friction, is the kinetic energy. From that, you find speed.

The friction force varies as the rope moves because the normal force (I.e. weight) varies with the length of rope still on the table. That varies from the full weight for the first bit of distance to zero for the last. You can handle that with calculus, or realize that this is a linear effect which allows you to average: the average weight, 1/2 the total, times the distance times the kinetic coefficient is the work done.

Answer (score 0):

The work of the friction force is proportional to the length of the rope that's already on the table. Suppose that length is $x$. The friction force is $F(x)=K_k x$. The work done by that force as your rope moves down by dx is $-F(x)dx$. The total work done by the friction is $|W|=\int_0^{l/3} K_k x dx$.

Knowing the work, you can look at the difference of potential energy, and from the energy conservation, you can obtain the kinetic energy by subtracting it.

You should also look at the static friction, to make sure your rope slides off the table.

If you haven't done calculus before, you should notice that the friction force is proportional to the length of rope on the table ($F=-K_k x$). This looks a lot like the force in a compressed spring. You could calculate the work done by friction the same way you do it for springs.